# YOLO3 can't run on GTX 2080 TI?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, nvidia, yolo

I'm runing YOLO3 on GTX 2080 TI and the program stop at the following line :

```
# Run the yolo model
    out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes = sess.run([scores, boxes, classes], feed_dict={yolo_model.input: image_data,
K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

I wonder that yolo3 can run on GTX 2080 TI or not. Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: the program doesn't have error . It runs to the line above and stop